# Why can't GCC or Clang optimise enum vector-vs-array comparison?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, compiler-optimization, std-ranges

I was reviewing some code that collects an `std::unordered_set` of enums and checks if there is exactly one specific value in the set, like:

```cpp
if (values.size () == 1 && *values.cbegin () == FOO) {
   // Something important
}
```

I suggested an alternative would be to do the comparison with `std::ranges::equal`, like so:

```cpp
if (std::ranges::equal (values, std::array {Foo})) {
   // Something important
}
```

This code is slightly less efficient - due to there being one additional comparison to check the size is one - than the first version, but reads nicer imho.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <unordered_set>

enum class Foo
{
    A, B, C
};

auto is_b_v1(const std::unordered_set<Foo> &v)
{
    return v.size () == 1 && *v.cbegin () == Foo::B;
}

auto is_b_v2(const std::unordered_set<Foo> &v)
{
    return std::ranges::equal (v, std::array {Foo::B});
}
```

```
is_b_v1(std::unordered_set<Foo, std::hash<Foo>, std::equal_to<Foo>, std::allocator<Foo> > const&):
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi+24], 1
        je      .L5
        ret
.L5:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 1
        sete    al
        ret
is_b_v2(std::unordered_set<Foo, std::hash<Foo>, std::equal_to<Foo>, std::allocator<Foo> > const&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L10
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 1
        jne     .L10
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
        sete    al
        ret
.L10:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v79r7b4T4

I was interested to see if the difference would be eliminated if the `std::unordered_set` was replaced with `std::vector`, since the size is then just a pointer diff. However, much to my surprise, the assembly for the `std::ranges` version with `std::vector` was substantially worse:

```
is_b_v1(std::vector<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> > const&):
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        xor     edx, edx
        sub     rax, rcx
        cmp     rax, 4
        jne     .L1
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rcx], 1
        sete    dl
.L1:
        mov     eax, edx
        ret
is_b_v2(std::vector<Foo, std::allocator<Foo> > const&):
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 1
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     rsi, rcx
        sub     rsi, rax
        cmp     rsi, 4
        jne     .L5
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L9
        lea     rdx, [rsp-4]
        jmp     .L7
.L12:
        add     rax, 4
        add     rdx, 4
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L9
.L7:
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax], esi
        je      .L12
        xor     edx, edx
.L5:
        mov     eax, edx
        ret
.L9:
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     eax, edx
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6njnrx37n

Switching the enum to an `int` makes the assembly identical (https://godbolt.org/z/hWaGqzer4). This hold for both GCC and Clang (though Clang produces different code in both cases), which makes me think that I'm missing something - why can't the enum version be optimised in the same way as the `int` one?

Comment: I don't think you're missing something, I think the optimizer is failing, badly, here. The `std::unordered_set` version is able to figure out that no loop is needed given it's exactly one item or it's not equal, the `std::vector` version is producing what you'd expect for a loop over a collection of any length, but the loop only gets entered when the length is exactly 1.

Comment: It would be slightly easier to follow the asm if the value you're searching for had a special numeric value like `B=42` or at least `C=2`, not `1` which also appears as a length and as the `true` return value.  https://godbolt.org/z/Pqbaqq7jP

Comment: Looks like a missed-optimization bug in GCC and Clang.  If there isn't already a report open for this kind of optimization (loops over compile-time-constant size and value arrays of enums vs. ints), you can report it https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ and https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/